# Supplying connection argument in mysqli_query(arg1,arg2) . dbConnection is on separate file

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm new to `mysqli` and still studying the changes in syntax as compared to the old style of coding where most are prefixed only by `mysql` instead of mysqli. 
So my problem is how to supply the **connection** argument in `mysqli_query()` method.

The syntax says that both `connection` and `query` are required to be supplied when using this function.
Syntax:

```
mysqli_query(connection,query,resultmode);
```

If I'm maintaining one `.php` file for my dbconnection which I'm including in other php files through the use of `include()` function, what should I put as connection argument in `mysqli_query(arg1,arg2,arg3);`

Here's my code.

```
<?php include('dbConnection.php') ?> # this, I added to avoid retyping
<?php
    if( isset($_POST['searchkeyword']) ){
        $var = $_POST['searchkeyword'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM student_info WHERE (STUD_NO LIKE '%$var%' OR NAME LIKE '%$var%' )";
        $resultSet = mysqli_query($query); # gets the result set returned by SELECT statement

        while($rsArray = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultSet)){
            $studno = $rsArray['stud_no'];
            $lastName = $rsArray['lname'];
            $firstName = $rsArray['fname'];
            $middleName = $rsArray['mname'];
            $address = $rsArray['address'];
            $city = $rsArray['city'];
            $gender = $rsArray['gender'];
            $enrolled = $rsArray['enrollment_stat']; 
            echo $studno."<br/>";
            echo $lastName.", ".$firstName." ".$middleName."<br/>";
            echo $address."<br/>";
            echo $city."<br/>";
            echo $gender."<br/>";
            echo $enrolled."<br/>";
        }      
    } 
?>
```

And here's the code for dbConnection.php

```
<?php
# this it the connection php file to include
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpassword = "";
    $dbname = "stud_data";
    $connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpassword,$dbname); # connection to mysql

    if(mysqli_connect_errno() > 0){
        echo "<script>window.alert('Failed To Connect To Database')</script>";
    }


?>
```

And I get this warning.

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\...on line 7

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\...on line 9
```

I'd appreciate any advice. 
Thanks.

Comment: can you show `dbConnection.php` code also?

Comment: So, did you try mysqli_query(arg1,arg2)?

Comment: @Anant thanks for your response. Added it.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I actually tried that but since these files are in separate php files, the $connection variable in dbConnection.php cannot be referenced within the other php file where I'm using the mysqli_query() I included the dbConnection.php file through the include() function.

Comment: @p3ace    in your code first add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` before  `include('dbConnection.php')` and also change  `$resultSet = mysqli_query($query);` to `$resultSet = mysqli_query($connection,$query);`

Answer (score -1):

Hope below snippet will give you idea--

```
mysqli_query($connection,"Your query here");
```

---

```
<?php include('dbConnection.php') ?> # this, I added to avoid retyping
<?php
    if( isset($_POST['searchkeyword']) ){
        $var = $_POST['searchkeyword'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM student_info WHERE (STUD_NO LIKE '%$var%' OR NAME LIKE '%$var%' )";

        $resultSet = mysqli_query($connection , $query); # gets the result set returned by SELECT statement

        while($rsArray = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultSet)){
            $studno = $rsArray['stud_no'];
            $lastName = $rsArray['lname'];
            $firstName = $rsArray['fname'];
            $middleName = $rsArray['mname'];
            $address = $rsArray['address'];
            $city = $rsArray['city'];
            $gender = $rsArray['gender'];
            $enrolled = $rsArray['enrollment_stat']; 
            echo $studno."<br/>";
            echo $lastName.", ".$firstName." ".$middleName."<br/>";
            echo $address."<br/>";
            echo $city."<br/>";
            echo $gender."<br/>";
            echo $enrolled."<br/>";
        }      
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm actually familiar of adding the $connection as argument. However, they're on separate files. I use include('dbConnection.php') to include it. Unless there's a way to store the include('dbConnection.php') to a variable $connection